# Como llenar un select dependiente de otro a travez de un select2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, select2, html-select, multiselect

Amigos, tengo un formulario para capturar unas encuestas, los campos de selección son dependientes, es decir, selecciono 1 (departamentos) y el otro select me muestra, a partir de esa seleccion, los datos correspondientes al valor del 1er select, es decir select1 = departamentos -> select2 = municipios, select3 -> instituciones (que están en el departamento seleccionado) y por último un select4 -> sedes.
También tengo otro select, utilizando el plugin "select2" y ahi busco los datos de la base, cuando selecciono 1 dato, él debería llenarme toda la información en los campos antes mencionados, el tema es que sólo me llena 1, les dejo el código a ver si de esa manera se entiende mejor.

```js
$('select[name=departamento]').select2();
$('select[name=municipio]').select2();
$('select[name=institucion]').select2();
$('select[name=departamento]').select2();
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
var encuesta = "";
var municipio = "";
var crear_encuesta = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
  get_auditor();
  get_encuesta();
  get_dptos();

  $("#cerrar").click(function() {
    $('#container').addClass('d-none');
  });

})
$('#departamento').change(function() {
  var parametros = "id=" + $("#departamento").val();
  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'datos_municipios.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      $("#municipio").html(response);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error")
    }

  });
})

$('#municipio').change(function() {
  var parametros = "id=" + $("#municipio").val();

  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'datos_institucion.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      $("#institucion").html(response);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error")
    }
  });
})
$('#institucion').change(function() {
  var parametros = "id=" + $("#institucion").val();
  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'datos_sede.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      $("#sede").html(response);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error")
    }
  });
})

function get_dptos() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'controlador_departamentos.php',
    data: {
      metodo: 'listado'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      departamento = JSON.parse(data);
      $('select[name=departamento]').append('<option value=""></option>');
      for (var i = 0; i < departamento.length; i++) {
        $('select[name=departamento]').append('<option value="' + departamento[i]['dpto_id'] + '">' + departamento[i]['dpto_nombre'] + '</option>');
      }
      $('select[name=departamento]').select2();

    }
  });
}

function enviar_form() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'controlador_encuestas01.php',
    data: $('#form_encuesta').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'ok') {
        toastr.success('Registro creado.');
      } else {
        toastr.error('Ocurrió un error inesperado');
      }

    }
  });
}

function eliminar() {
  $('#metodo').val('eliminar');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'controlador_encuestas01.php',
    data: $('#form_encuesta').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'ok') {
        toastr.success('Registro Eliminado');
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload()
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
}

function get_encuesta() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'controlador_encuestas01.php',
    data: {
      metodo: 'listado'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      encuesta = JSON.parse(data);
      $('select[name=bus_enc]').append('<option value=""></option>');
      for (var i = 0; i < encuesta.length; i++) {
        $('select[name=bus_enc]').append('<option value="' + encuesta[i]['enc01_id'] + '">' + encuesta[i]['nom_encuestado'] + '</option>');
      }
      $('select[name=bus_enc]').select2();
    }
  });
}

function get_auditor() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'controlador_auditores.php',
    data: {
      metodo: 'listado'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      persona = JSON.parse(data);
      $('select[name=auditor]').append('<option value=""></option>');
      for (var i = 0; i < persona.length; i++) {
        $('select[name=auditor]').append('<option value="' + persona[i]['auditor_id'] + '">' + persona[i]['auditor_apellido1'] + ' ' + persona[i]['auditor_nombre1'] + ' - ' + persona[i]['auditor_ced'] + '' + '</option>');
      }
      $('select[name=auditor]').select2();
    }
  });
}


$('select[name=bus_enc]').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $('select[name=bus_enc] :selected').val();
  $('input[name=enc01_id]').val('');
  $('input[name=enc01_fecha]').val('');
  $('select[name=departamento]').val('');
  $('select[name=departamento]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=municipio]').val('');
  $('select[name=municipio]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=institucione]').val('');
  $('select[name=institucione]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=sede]').val('');
  $('select[name=sede]').trigger('change');
  $('input[name=nom_encuestado').val('');
  $('input[name=cargo_encuesta').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp01]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp01]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp02]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp02]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp03]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp03]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp04]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp04]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp05]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp05]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp06]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp06]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp07]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp07]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp08]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp08]').trigger('change');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp09]').val('');
  $('select[name=enc01_resp09]').trigger('change');
  $('textarea[name=enc01_notas').val('');
  $('select[name=auditor]').val('');
  $('select[name=auditor]').trigger('change');

  for (var i = 0; i < encuesta.length; i++) {
    if (encuesta[i]['enc01_id'] == selected) {
      console.log(encuesta);
      $('input[name=enc01_id]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_id']);
      $('input[name=enc01_fecha]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_fecha']);
      $('select[name=departamento]').val(encuesta[i]['dpto_nombre']);
      $('select[name=departamento]').trigger('change');
      $('select[name=municipio]').val(encuesta[i]['munic_nombre']);
      $('select[name=municipio]').trigger('change');
      $('select[name=institucion]').val(encuesta[i]['ieds_nombre']);
      $('select[name=institucion]').trigger('change');
      $('select[name=sede]').val(encuesta[i]['sede_nombre']);
      $('select[name=sede]').trigger('change');
      $('input[name=nom_encuestado]').val(encuesta[i]['nom_encuestado']);
      $('input[name=cargo_encuesta]').val(encuesta[i]['cargo_encuesta']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp01]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp01']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp02]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp02']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp03]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp03']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp04]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp04']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp05]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp05']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp06]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp06']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp07]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp07']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp08]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp08']);
      $('[name=enc01_resp09]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_resp09']);
      $('textarea[name=enc01_notas]').val(encuesta[i]['enc01_notas']);
      $('select[name=auditor]').val(encuesta[i]['auditor']);
      $('select[name=auditor]').trigger('change');
      $('#nuevo_personal').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#refresh').removeClass('d-none');
      $('#delete').removeClass('d-none');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.select2-selection {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: calc(1.5em + 1rem) !important;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem !important;
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 1.5 !important;
  color: #495057 !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  background-clip: padding-box !important;
  border: 0.125rem solid #ced4da !important;
  border-radius: 0.5rem !important;
}

form {
  background: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  width: 850px;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #3d7ba8;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <!-- meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
  <title>Controlador</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
  <section id="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container ">
      <div class="row" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(50, 0, 180, 0.2);">
        <form action="" id="form_encuesta" method="post" style="background:#DBECEC;" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="metodo" id="metodo" value="insertar">
          <input type="hidden" name="enc01_id" value="">
          <div class="card-heading">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="cerrar">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h2 class="title" style="text-align:center;"><b>ENCUESTA PARA RECTORES</b></h2>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] == 1) { ?>
              <div id="bus_enc">
                <label>Busqueda</label>
                <select name="bus_enc" class="custom-select" style="text-transform:uppercase;" style="width: 100%">
                </select>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div>
                <label>Departamento</label>
                <input type="text" id="departamento_base" class="d-none" name="departamento_base">
                <select name="departamento" id="departamento" class="custom-select">
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Campo Requerido
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div>
                <label>Municipio</label>
                <input type="text" id="municipio_base" class="d-none" name="municipio_base">
                <select name="municipio" id="municipio" class="custom-select">
                  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div>
                <label>Institución</label>
                <input type="text" id="institucion_base" class="d-none" name="institucion_base">
                <select name="institucion" id="institucion" class="custom-select">
                  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div>
                <label>Sede</label>
                <input type="text" id="sede_base" class="d-none" name="sede_base">
                <select name="sede" id="sede" class="custom-select">
                  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
              <label>Nombre Encuestado:</label>
              <input type="text" name="nom_encuestado" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Campo Requerido
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <label>Cargo:</label>
              <input type="text" name="cargo_encuesta" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Campo Requerido
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <label>Fecha de Visita:</label>
              <input type="date" name="enc01_fecha" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Campo Requerido
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="table table-striped w-auto">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">1. ¿Con qué frecuencia es visitada la I.E.D por parte de los supervisores del contrato de Aseo?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp01" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Semanal">SEMANAL</option>
                        <option value="Mensual">MENSUAL</option>
                        <option value="Quincenal">QUINCENAL</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">2. ¿Se cumple con la realización de aseo en las instituciones Educativas?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp02" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">3. ¿Considera que es eficiente la labor que realiza el personal que tiene asignado en la I.E.D.?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp03" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">4. ¿El personal asignado por el contratista cuenta con las herramientas necesarias?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp04" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">5. ¿El personal contratado cumple con el horario estipulado para ejecutar sus actividades?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp05" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">6. ¿Quién suministro los insumos de aseo para las labores administrativas?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp06" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Institucion">Institución</option>
                        <option value="Contratista">Contratista</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">7. ¿Ha tenido inconveniente con algún trabajador del contratista durante la ejecucion del contrato?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp07" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">8. ¿Como evalua la labor del contratista?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp08" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Buena">BUENA</option>
                        <option value="Regular">REGULAR</option>
                        <option value="Mala">MALA</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">9. ¿Se han realizado brigadas mensuales de aseo a los trabajadores?</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="select" style="width: 190px;">
                      <select name="enc01_resp09" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN</option>
                        <option value="Si">SI</option>
                        <option value="No">NO</option>
                        <option value="No Responde">NO RESPONDE</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="enc01_notas">¿Desea realizar algún comentario adicional?</label>
                <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="enc01_notas" name="enc01_notas" rows="3" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" value="" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div id="auditor">
                <label>Auditor</label>
                <select name="auditor" class="custom-select" style="width: 100%" required>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Campo Requerido
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" style="float: right; color: white; margin: 5px;" onclick="enviar_form();" id="nuevo_personal" title="Guardar Encuesta">
              Guardar
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-success d-none" id="refresh" style="float: right; color: white; margin: 5px;" onClick="location.reload();" title="Recarga la pagina">Deshacer
            </button>
            <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] == 1) { ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger d-none" id="delete" style="float: right; color: white; margin: 5px;" onclick="eliminar();" title="Eliminar Encuesta">
                Eliminar
              </button>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```